# Array exception Values not inserting

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I have two `JTable`s. For example TB1 and TB2, only have single column each.

Each table contains some values. Or the second table may be empty.
All I need is to

1. Add values of TB1 to TB2.
2. also need to compare both table values and write it to TB2, without replication

   I am using netbeans-8.

   ```
   String[] Ary = {};
   Vector R_D=new Vector();
   int found=0;
   for(int i=0;i<=t1.getRowCount()-1;i++){
       System.out.println(t1.getRowCount());

           for(int j=0;j<=t2.getRowCount()-1;j++){

                   if(t1.getValueAt(i, 0)!=t2.getValueAt(j, 0)){
                       System.err.println("Compare "+t1.getValueAt(i,     0)+"and "+t2.getValueAt(j, 0));

                       found=0;
                   }
                   else{
                       found=1;
                       System.err.println("Found Match at +t1.getValueAt(i,  0)+"and "+t2.getValueAt(j, 0));
                   }

           }
           if(found==0){
                       Ary[i]=t1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();                    
                       R_D.add(t1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
           }
               ((DefaultTableModel) t2.getModel()).insertRow(i, R_D);
   }
   ```

   At this portion 
   `Ary[i]=t1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();`
   I am getting some error message like:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

How can I avoid this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] Ary = {};
```

You are creating an empty array.

Maybe you want something like:

```
String[] array = new String[t1.getRowCount()];
```

Now you have an array the same size as the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Thank you friend.That's the right answer.But how can we make an array without replication.

Comment: @Vijay, `That's the right answer` - then your original question is solved so the question should be "accepted" by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.. `But how can we make an array without replication` well that is a different question. I would not use an Array. I would use a Set. Then you just add the values to the Set. After all values have been added, the Set will contain the unique values.